# Is the converse of if $a=b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$ not necessarily true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $a=b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$ is the definition of a function.

However, its converse if $f(a)=f(b)$, then $a=b$ is not necessarily true. The converse is only true if $f(x)$ is a "one-to-one" function, right?

Edit:

This is because if $f(x)$ is not a "non-one-to-one" function, then there will be multiple inputs that correspond (map to) the same output, so we cannot assume that   $f(a)=f(b)$  implies $a=b$ since there will be multiple input values that satisfy the equation (produce said output). To assume so would "miss" the other solutions (input values). For example, $f(x)= x^2$

$x^2=2^2\longrightarrow x=2$

while true misses the other solution (input value) $x=-2$ which produces the same output.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the motivation for introducing the notion : Injective functions are exactly those functions for which the converse is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the statement

$$f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b$$

or the equivalent

$$a\neq b \implies f(a)\neq f(b)$$

is the definition of [injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) and it justify the solution for equations like

$$\log A(x)= \log B(x) \implies A(x)=B(x)$$

providing that $A(x)>0$.

For the same reason when $f(x)$ is not injective we need to pay attention, as for example

$$\sin A(x) = \sin (B(x) \implies A(x)=B(x)$$

which is wrong.